# Why i can't access protected property in the derived class

Tags: c#, polymorphism, access-modifiers

I have a two classes.This is my code:

```
//My Base class
public class People
    {
       public People()
       {
       }

        protected string name;

        protected string Name
           {
        get 
        {
            return this.name;
        }
        set 
        {
            this.name = value;
        }
    }

    }

//The Child class 

public class Student:People
    {
        private int id;

        public Student()
        { 
        }

        public Student (int id, string name)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.Name = name;
        }

        public int ID
        {
            get
            {
                return this.id;
            }

            set

            {
                this.id = value;
            }

        }
    }
```

When i create instance of the Student class like the one below i can't access the NAME property from the parent class People.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Student student1 = new Student();
            student1. // only ID property is accessible 

        }
    }
```

Do i make something wrong? Since Students is child class of People i expected that the NAME property should be accessible trough the Student instances.Thank you very much for the help in advance.

Comment: It's accessible IN the children instances. You have to make it public to have it accessible from the outside. You can read more about access modifiers [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx)

Comment: I'd totally shorten the first bit to protected string Name {get;set;}

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault You can put that as the answer

Comment: @MikeyMouse Meh not really, a comment does the job, OP gets notified anyway. And there's not much to tell besides "use public and read the doc".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong, but if you want to access

```
Name
```

via an instance of

```
Student
```

You have to declare that property `public`. Otherwise, only access from within that class is allowed (not via an instance).

Answer (score 2):

You are still accessing it Outside the class so it would need to be public.

You can read about access modifiers here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx

Change your properties to:

```
public string Name {get;set;}
```

And you should be good to go.

Answer (score 1):

The Student class does not expose the `Name` property to the outside.
If you would derive a class from student, you could access the `Name` property.
Alternatively, you could reimplement `Name` using the `new` keyword like this:

```
public class Student : People
    {
        private int id;

        public new String Name { get; set;}

        public Student()
        {
        }

        public Student(int id, string name)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.Name = name;
        }



        public int ID
        {
            get
            {
                return this.id;
            }

            set
            {
                this.id = value;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Keep in mind though that you should seriously consider making the `Name` property public in the base class instead of using the `new` keyword.
(only use this if it is somehow crucial that the base class does not expose `Name`)

Answer (score 1):

you should make your `Properties public`

```
//My Base class
public class People
    {
       public People()
       {
       }

        protected string name;

        public string Name
           {
        get 
        {
            return this.name;
        }
        set 
        {
            this.name = value;
        }
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not access `protected` property of base class using instance of a *derived* class. 
Protected property if a property that can be accessed only within bounds of derived types.

If you need to access to that property from instance of the `Student`, declare it like a public inside its base class: `People`.

If you also need in some way *override* its behavior, can declare it `public virtual` in base class and *override* it in `Student`

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is that your protected fields are in the base class not the inherited class. Look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a.aspx

```
public class BaseClass
{
public string foo
}

public class SubClass
{
protected string bar
}
```

This is a more common use of protected.